# Pass variables to "Execute Windows Batch Command" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to pass the ${BUILD_NUMBER} to both nuget and to octo during a build in jenkins.

I do not want to use a specific batch file

```
nuget pack -Version 1.1.${BUILD_NUMBER} 

octo.exe push --package "C:\Jenkins\workspace\MyWorkspace\MyProject.1.1.${BUILD_NUMBER}.nupkg"
```

How would I be able to parameterize the above commands to include the correct build number?

**Solution** :

```
nuget pack -Version 1.1.%BUILD_NUMBER%

octo.exe push --package "C:\Jenkins\workspace\MyWorkspace\MyProject.1.1.%BUILD_NUMBER%.nupkg"
```

[image]

Comment: so you want to push the build number as a variable to use elsewhere in the script?

Comment: yes sir, I dont have the luxury of a actual build in this project (there is no csproj or sln). So instead of the normal parameters I pass to msbuild, i now have to pack this on my own. (Eks ook in Bellville!)

Comment: Nice. werk of bly in Bellville?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the default windows technique  %...% for passing your variables along.

In your example you'd get

```
nuget pack -Version 1.1.%BUILD_NUMBER%
```